# How to move contents from one stack to another?

Tags: c++

I want to move the contents from the stack inbox to outbox, and then return the top of outbox. But the return type of pop is void, so the code throws an error saying:  void value not ignored as it ought to be.

How can the values be moved?

Here is the code:

```
template <class E>
class Queue
{

    private:
        stack<E> inbox;
        stack<E> outbox;

    public:
     void enqueue(E item) {
        inbox.push(item);
    }

    E dequeue() {
        if (outbox.empty()) {
            while (!inbox.empty()) {
                outbox.push(inbox.pop());
            }
        }

        return outbox.pop();
    }

};
```

Comment: Looking at the [documentation of stack](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/stack) you would find [top()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/stack/top).

Comment: If you're talking about the standard library - why not have a look at the stack api? Pop isn't used for returning an object, it just removes the top object.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's `stack::top` that returns the top of the stack. `stack::pop` just removes the top element *without* returning it.

```
E dequeue() {
    if (outbox.empty()) {
        while (!inbox.empty()) {
            outbox.push(inbox.top());
            inbox.pop();
        }
    }
    E ret = outbox.top();
    outbox.pop();
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: For reference, [GOTW 8](http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/008.htm) shows the reason for designing the interface this way, in a comment on the solutions pop method. It's old though, so perhaps don't take the rest as gospel.

Answer (score 0):

You can access the the last element with `top()` and then remove it from the stack with `pop()`. See [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stack/stack/) for a good reference.

Answer (score 0):

`inbox.pop` simply removes the top element from the stack.
`inbox.top` returns the top element, after which you can use `inbox.pop` to remove it.